# foreach loop not finding var

Tags: php, loops, variables, foreach

So basically the loop runs trough a text file which is in my project folder.
 And what I'm trying to do while printing them out to a web-page is finding one specific id which would be `$id` I've tried echoing out $id to see if is actually there and it is. So I'm not too sure why this isn't working. Keep in mind I am new to PHP so its probably something dumb :p

```
 <?php
    require 'steamauth/steamauth.php';
    require 'steamauth/userInfo.php';

    $id = $_SESSION['steamid'];
    $pid = $id;
    echo "pid = $pid \n" . "<br />";
    $lines = file('admins.txt');
    foreach ($lines as $line_num => $line) {
        echo "" . htmlspecialchars($line) . "<br />\n";
        if($line == $id){
          echo "found";
        }
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: `if(strpos($id,$line)!== false){
          echo "found";
        }`  also `session_start();` needed

Comment: Why are you assigning a value to $id and then assigning the value of $id to $pid?  Seems kind of redundant to me

Comment: @Anant Your test would trigger false positives.  "102" would match "10210", etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First:-

***`session_start()`; missing on the page code***

Then

Based on manual:-http://php.net/manual/en/function.file.php

Use `FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES` like below:-

```
$lines = file('admins.txt', FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);
```

Now check:-

```
 if($line == $id){
    echo "found";
 }
```

Or

```
if(strpos($id,$line)!==false){
  echo "found";
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Add a trim before comparring to the line content to $id

```
<?php
  require 'steamauth/steamauth.php';
  require 'steamauth/userInfo.php';

  $id = $_SESSION['steamid'];
  $pid = $id;
  echo "pid = $pid \n" . "<br />";
  $lines = file('admins.txt');
  foreach ($lines as $line_num => $line) {
        echo "" . htmlspecialchars($line) . "<br />\n";
        if(trim($line) == trim($id)){
           echo "found";
        }
  }
?>
```